# How does a Cloud Function instance handles multiple requests?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I trying to wrap my head around Cloud Function's instances and how they work.

I'm asking about an example of an HTTP function, but I think the concept applies to any kind of function.

- Let's say I have this cloud function that handles **SSR** for my app, named `ssrApp`.
- And let's assume that it takes `1 second` to complete every time it gets a request.
- When Cloud Function receives the 1st request, it will spin up an instance to respond it.

**QUESTION**

**How does that instance behave when multiple requests are coming?**

From: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec

> Each instance of a function handles only one concurrent request at a time. **This means that while your code is processing one request, there is no possibility of a second request being routed to the same instance.** Thus the original request can use the full amount of resources (CPU and memory) that you requested.

Does it mean that during that `1 second` when my `ssrApp` function is running, if somebody hits my app URL, **it is guaranteed that Cloud Function will spin up another instance** for that second request? Does it matter if the function does only `sync` calls or some `async` calls in its execution? What I mean is, could an `async` call free the instance to respond to another request in parallel?

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single specific question per post on Stack Overflow.  What you have is too broad.  Consider also that there are discussion groups that might be better suited to broad questioning, such as Reddit.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the feedback, Doug. I've refactored my question into a single topic, which I think now is a valid question. I've read the docs but I still would like to have a better understanding of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does it mean that during that 1 second when my ssrApp function is running, if somebody hits my app URL, it is guaranteed that Cloud Function will spin up another instance for that second request?

That's the general behavior, although there are no guarantees around scheduling.

> Does it matter if the function does only sync calls or some async calls in its execution? What I mean is, could an async call free the instance to respond to another request in parallel?

No, that makes no difference. If the container is waiting for an async call, it it still considered to be in-use.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. Good to know that.

Answer (score 1):

**2022 Update**

For future searchers, Cloud Functions Gen2 now supports concurrency: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/2nd-gen/configuration-settings#concurrency

Comment: URL changed: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/concurrency